# Jenkins powershell plugin don't work in declarative pipeline

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I'm trying to run a powershell script in a declarative pipeline job, but it don't work. It seems to work, but don't do nothing.

This is a part of my pipeline

```
pipeline{
    agent{
        label 'windows'
    }
    stages {
        .
        .
        .
        stage("Preparing"){
            steps{
                powershell "./scripts/SetVersion.ps1 $version"
            }
        }
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

This is the output in pipeline log

```
Running PowerShell script
```

But nothing happens and the pipeline go to the next step. And for sure my script was not run. The same instruction runs very well in scriptable pipeline

I tried basic commands like "ps" and it worked well.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this plugin buggy?

Some additional information

Jenkins version: 2.107.2

Powershell plugin version: 1.3

Comment: Is the path correct? Also, try with double backslashes in path instead of forward-slash.

Comment: @Vasan tryied as you suggested. Same problem. Also, the path is correct. If it wasn't correct, I would get an not found error. I tested it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

False alarm. It was just another job breaking my scripts.
Everything is ok now.